# Google Sheets Macro Input Form Malformed HTML Content

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating an employee maintenance system for my organization in Google Sheets.

Within Code.gs, I have an HTML form.

When I put everything within the body tags in a regular HTML file, the form looks exactly as I expect it to. But in Google Sheets, I get an error. I have only seen examples with inline styling so please forgive me. I'm a newb at this.

```js
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('<body bgcolor=#0082ca><p>Enter new Employee Details</input></p><br><form action="/action_page.php"><div id="fields" style="width:330px;"><p>First name: <input style="margin-bottom:5px;float:right;"type="text" name="fName"></input></p><p>Last name: <input style="margin-bottom:5px;float:right;"type="text" name="lName"></input></p><p>email: <input style="margin-bottom:5px;float:right;"type="email" name="email"></input></p><p>Cell: <input style="margin-bottom:5px;float:right;"type="phone" name="cell"></input></p><p>Direct Line: <input style="margin-bottom:5px;float:right;"type="phone" name="dLine"></input></p><p>Extension: <input style="margin-bottom:5px;float:right;"type="text" name="ext"></input></p><p>Start Date: <input style="margin-bottom:5px;float:right;width:172px;"type="date" name="sDate"></input></p><p><div id="empType" style="border-color:black;border-width:1px;border-type:solid;"><div id="empTypeRadios" style="display:inline-block;width:330px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;border-radius:25px 25px 0 0;"><div style="display:block;float:left;position:relative;width:50%;margin-top:5px;"><input type="radio" name="payType" value="Hourly"><label="payType">Hourly</label></input></div><div style="display:block;position:relative;float:left;width:50%;margin-top:5px;" ><input type="radio" name="payType" value="Salary"><label="payType">Salary</label></input></div></div></div></div></p><p><div id="company"><div id="companyRadios" style="width:330px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;"><div style="display:block;float:left;position:relative;width:50%;margin-top:5px;"><input type="radio" name="company" value="CompanyA"><label="company">CompanyA</label></input></div><div style="display:block;position:relative;float:left;width:50%;margin-top:5px;" ><input style="display:block;position:relative;float:left;" type="radio" name="company" value="CompanyB"><label="company">CompanyB</label></input></div></div></div></div></p><p><div id="action" style="border-color:black;border-width:1px;border-type:solid;"><div id="actionRadios" style="display:inline-block;width:330px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;border-radius:0 0 25px 25px;"><div style="display:block;float:left;position:relative;width:33%;margin-top:5px;"><input type="radio" name="action" value="Add"><label"action">Add </label></input></div><div style="display:block;float:left;position:relative;width:33%;margin-top:5px;"><input type="radio" name="action"  value="Modify"><label"action">Modify </label></input></div><div style="display:block;float:left;position:relative;width:33%;margin-top:5px;"><input type="radio" name="action" value="Archive"><label="action">Archive </label></input></div></div></div></div></p><p><div style="display:block;position:relative;float:left;width:50%;" ><input style="clear:float;margin-bottom:5px;float:left;width:98%;"type="submit" value="Submit"></div><div style="display:block;position:relative;float:left;width:50%;" ><input style="clear:float;margin-bottom:5px;float:left;width:98%;"type="submit" value="Clear"></div></div></form></body>')
  .setWidth(350)
  .setHeight(400);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Employee Add/Archive');
```

Comment: Welcome. Some tags have some use guidelines, so before adding a tag, checkout it excerpt and if you need more details checkout the tag wiki. By the other hand, questions that look for help with non-working code should include a [mcve].

Comment: I'd recommend that you start with a much simpler html page. The problem is not with the HtmlService.  It's the html input.  There are fair number of html errors and oddities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes so my problem was that I screwed up and added tags to close the input. 
I had some other jacked-up html too.

I don't know what I was smoking or drinking (since I don't smoke and hadn't been drinking in months) but I now have the form I wanted.

Additionally, I found a better way to serve the HTML here using two files instead of one: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/